# Trouble downloading Geodatabase wetlands from FWS.gov

Tags: download

Have tried using every browser (chrome, firefox, safari, ie, opera) to download wetland data from:
[FWS.gov wetland data download](http://www.fws.gov/wetlands/Data/State-Downloads.html) with no luck. It either chokes around 400 MB or finishes up with a corrupted zip file which cannot be opened.
It is only an issue with the larger .gdb files (over 400 MB), like Texas which is 1.7 GB.

Any ideas on how to download these files without error?

Comment: Have you tried a download manager?

Comment: I had the same problem.  It always failed on my slower work connection, but succeeded on first try at my faster home connection.  I can only guess that their server times out if a download takes too long.

Comment: email 'Wetlands_Team@fws.gov' there server is timing out with users sessions.

Comment: Jason's download manager suggestion worked. I found GetGo http://download.cnet.com/GetGo-Download-Manager/3000-2071_4-10277023.html to work the best after trying several of them.

Comment: @sirgeo You might want to post that as a solution to your problem and accept it. That way, others would know that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like @Jason had the right idea by suggesting the use of a download manager.  It's likely that the server has a limitation on bandwidth per connection, which is circumvented by a download manager's ability to perform multiple simultaneous connections through a multipart download.

The download manager will also be able to deal with interruptions in the connection by pausing and resuming once the connection is reestablished, which would help if the issue is server timeout.